# i'm trying to get the sum of the pending amount of each individual team which i'm getting in tree view

Tags: php, mysql

this is my Php code which i'm using to generate three structure

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); //no limit
ini_set("memory_limit",-1);
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root');
mysql_select_db('testdb');

$qry="SELECT Id, SuperseniorMasterId, SubmasterId, TotalDP_Inst_Pending FROM treeview";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $data[] = $row;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(buildtree($data));
echo '</pre>';

function buildtree($src_arr, $parent_id = 0, $tree = array())
{

    foreach($src_arr as $idx => $row)
    {
        if($row['SuperseniorMasterId'] == $parent_id)
        {
            foreach($row as $k => $v)
                $tree[$row['SubmasterId']][$k] = $v;
                unset($src_arr[$idx]);
                $tree[$row['SubmasterId']]['children'] = buildtree($src_arr, $row['SubmasterId']);

        }
    }
    ksort($tree);
    return $tree;
}
?>
```

and now i'm trying to calculate the sum of column TotalDP_Inst_Pending  for each individual team and store it in variable.
please help me solve the issue..

i'm getting tree view as below

[image]

Comment: please help me....

Comment: is anyone their??? please help me sort out this